# XML Formatting Issue

Tags: xml, soap, lxml

I am using the Salesforce SOAP API for the first time, and so I'm not familiar with SOAP formatting issues, etc.  I am using the `lxml` library to generate the XML, but seem to have a formatting issue.

The error I receive is: "The child of the Envelope element must be either a Header or Body element" which is strange, because when I review the XML generated by my SalesforceLeadConverter.build_xml() method, it looks right.  This is the

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <Header>
      <ns0:SessionHeader xmlns:ns0="urn">
          <ns0:sessionId>ldfkjskjdfksdfsdfsdf</ns0:sessionId>
      </ns0:SessionHeader>
   </Header>
   <Body>
      <ns1:convertLead xmlns:ns1="urn">
           <ns1:leadConverts>
               <ns1:leadId>00Qj000000PMV3h</ns1:leadId>
               <ns1:doNotCreateOpportunity>False</ns1:doNotCreateOpportunity>
               <ns1:sendNotificationEmail>False</ns1:sendNotificationEmail>
           </ns1:leadConverts>
       </ns1:convertLead>
   </Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Here is the full class and associated method for generating the XML:

```
from lxml import etree

class SalesforceLeadConverter(object):

    def __init__(self, session_id, lead_id, **kwargs):
        """ Provides functionality for converting a Lead to a new or existing
        Account and create a new Contact or update an existing Contact.

        account_id: Optional; if specified, converts the Lead to a Contact
        associated with this Account.

        contact_id: Optional; if specified, converts the Lead into an existing
        Contact record, preventing the creation of a duplicate.
        """

        self.session_id = session_id
        self.lead_id = lead_id
        self.account_id = kwargs.get('account_id', False)
        self.contact_id = kwargs.get('contact_id', False)
        self.converted_status = kwargs.get('converted_status', False)
        self.do_not_create_opportunity = str(kwargs.get('do_not_create_opportunity', False))
        self.opportunity_name = kwargs.get('opportunity_name', False)
        self.owner_id = kwargs.get('owner_id', False)
        self.send_notification_email = str(kwargs.get('send_notification_email', False))

    def build_xml(self):
        S_NS = 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'
        S_PRE = '{' + S_NS + '}'
        root = etree.Element(S_PRE + 'Envelope', nsmap={'soapenv': S_NS})
        soapenv = etree.SubElement(root, 'Header')
        header = etree.SubElement(soapenv, '{urn}SessionHeader')
        sid = etree.SubElement(header, '{urn}sessionId').text=self.session_id
        soapenv2 = etree.SubElement(root, 'Body')
        urn2 = etree.SubElement(soapenv2, '{urn}convertLead')
        lead_converts = etree.SubElement(urn2, '{urn}leadConverts')
        lead_id = etree.SubElement(
            lead_converts,
            '{urn}leadId'
            ).text=self.lead_id
        do_not_create_opportunity = etree.SubElement(
            lead_converts,
            '{urn}doNotCreateOpportunity'
            ).text=self.do_not_create_opportunity
        send_notification_email = etree.SubElement(
            lead_converts,
            '{urn}sendNotificationEmail'
            ).text=self.send_notification_email
        xml_meta = """<?xml version="1.1" encoding="utf-8"?>"""

        return xml_meta + etree.tostring(root, encoding='utf-8')
```

Answer (score 2):

SOAP Body and Header needs a namespace. 
Also your elements prefixed by ns0, ns1 neads a namespace declaration too.

So your valid SOAP will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns0="your_namespace_here" xmlns:ns1="your_namespace_here">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <ns0:SessionHeader xmlns:ns0="urn">
          <ns0:sessionId>ldfkjskjdfksdfsdfsdf</ns0:sessionId>
      </ns0:SessionHeader>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns1:convertLead xmlns:ns1="urn">
           <ns1:leadConverts>
               <ns1:leadId>00Qj000000PMV3h</ns1:leadId>
               <ns1:doNotCreateOpportunity>False</ns1:doNotCreateOpportunity>
               <ns1:sendNotificationEmail>False</ns1:sendNotificationEmail>
           </ns1:leadConverts>
       </ns1:convertLead>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Thanks, this put me on the right path!  I figured out that I needed to get rid of ns0 and ns1, and ultimately this post lead me to the required formatting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19909473/lxml-use-namespace-instead-of-ns0-ns1

Comment: I think I've cleared up the XML formatting / namespace issue, but now I'm getting the following error: "No operation available for request {urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com}convertLead"  -- any ideas on what I've done wrong with this one?

Answer (score 0):

The modified SalesforceLeadConverter class below resolved the header/body namespace issue (kudos to MGorgon for pointing me in the right direction).  [This StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19909473/lxml-use-namespace-instead-of-ns0-ns1) ultimately lead me to the right solution.

Note that while the namespace issue was resolved, the code below *still* doesn't work...there is another issue that popped up, where I'm getting the following error:

> "No operation available for request {enterprise.soap.sforce.com}convertLead"

Anyway, here's my soap.py file:

```
import requests
from lxml.etree import Element, SubElement, tostring


class SalesforceLeadConverter(object):

    def __init__(self, session_id, lead_id, **kwargs):
        """ Provides functionality for converting a Lead to a new or existing
        Account and create a new Contact or update an existing Contact.

        account_id: Optional; if specified, converts the Lead to a Contact
        associated with this Account.

        contact_id: Optional; if specified, converts the Lead into an existing
        Contact record, preventing the creation of a duplicate.
        """

        self.session_id = session_id
        self.lead_id = lead_id
        self.account_id = kwargs.get('account_id', False)
        self.contact_id = kwargs.get('contact_id', False)
        self.converted_status = kwargs.get('converted_status', False)
        self.do_not_create_opportunity = str(kwargs.get('do_not_create_opportunity', False))
        self.opportunity_name = kwargs.get('opportunity_name', False)
        self.owner_id = kwargs.get('owner_id', False)
        self.send_notification_email = str(kwargs.get('send_notification_email', False))

    def build_xml(self):
        schema_ns = 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'
        urn_ns = 'enterprise.soap.sforce.com'
        S_PRE = '{' + schema_ns + '}'
        envelope = Element(
            S_PRE + 'Envelope',
            nsmap={'soapenv': schema_ns, 'urn': urn_ns}
            )
        header = SubElement(envelope, '{%s}Header' % schema_ns)
        s_header = SubElement(header, '{%s}SessionHeader' % urn_ns)
        sid = SubElement(s_header, '{%s}sessionId' % urn_ns).text=self.session_id
        body = SubElement(envelope, '{%s}Body' % schema_ns)
        convert_lead = SubElement(body, '{%s}convertLead' % urn_ns)
        lead_converts = SubElement(convert_lead, '{%s}leadConverts' % urn_ns)
        lead_id = SubElement(
            lead_converts,
            '{%s}leadId' % urn_ns
            ).text=self.lead_id
        do_not_create_opportunity = SubElement(
            lead_converts,
            '{%s}doNotCreateOpportunity' % urn_ns
            ).text=self.do_not_create_opportunity
        send_notification_email = SubElement(
            lead_converts,
            '{%s}sendNotificationEmail' % urn_ns
            ).text=self.send_notification_email

        if self.account_id:
            account_id = SubElement(
                lead_converts,
                '{%s}accountId' % urn_ns
                ).text=self.account_id
        if self.contact_id:
            contact_id = SubElement(
                lead_converts,
                '{%s}contactId' % urn_ns
                ).text=self.contact_id
        if self.converted_status:
            converted_status = SubElement(
                lead_converts,
                '{%s}convertedStatus' % urn_ns
                ).text=self.converted_status
        xml_meta = """<?xml version="1.1" encoding="utf-8"?>"""

        return xml_meta + tostring(envelope, encoding='utf-8')

    def post(self):
        xml = self.build_xml()
        headers = {'Content-Type':'text/xml', 'SOAPAction':'convertLead'}
        url = 'https://na1.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/34.0'
        out = requests.post(url, data=xml, headers=headers)
        return out, out.text
```

Answer (score 0):

<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns0="your_namespace_here" xmlns:ns1="your_namespace_here">

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).